# Atxmega128a4 supported for assembler only - AVRSudio 5.1

Tags: c, gcc, avr, avr-studio5

I have changed my micro controller in order to have more flash memory size, so then I realized that my new MCU, atxmega128a4 is supported for assembler only. It is important to note that I am using Avrsudio 5.1. Is it possible to update gcc to compile my C project? Is there any extension to fix the problem? Or I must update AVRStudio to any higher version?

Comment: Can you use the newer Atmel studio 6?

Comment: What would be missing from Studio 5 would be the relevant include files and crt0. You could probably take them from an installation of Studio 6 and eventually make it work. It would be much easier to use Studio 6 if you can.